# Using Borrow trait with a referenced value

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a custom trait that I want to implement on a `HashMap<(u32, u32), &'a Edge>`. Since I want my trait to work on both owned and referenced values, I use the `Borrow` trait as suggested by other SO posts but I am having issues with the borrow checker and the referenced `&Edge`. First, the compiler wants me to specifically add a lifetime to `&Edge` which I did as you can see below.

However, then the compiler complains that the return type of the function `get_edge` (`Option<&'a Edge>`) does not match the return type of the trait definition (`Option<&Edge>`). In my opinion, it does not make sense to add lifetime parameters to my trait definition so I guess the error must be somewhere along my implementation of the trait. However, no matter what combinations of lifetime parameters I try, I haven't been able to make the compiler happy. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
pub struct Edge {
    between: (u32, u32),
    weight: u32,
}

impl Edge {
    pub fn normalize_edge(v1: u32, v2: u32) -> (u32, u32) {
        (v1.min(v2), v1.max(v2))
    }

    fn get_weight(&self) -> u32 {
        self.weight
    }
}

trait EdgeFinder {
    fn get_edge(&self, v1: u32, v2: u32) -> Option<&Edge>;
    fn get_weight(&self, v1: u32, v2: u32) -> Option<u32>;
}

impl<'a, 'b, B: Borrow<HashMap<(u32, u32), &'a Edge>> + 'b> EdgeFinder for B {
    fn get_edge(&self, v1: u32, v2: u32) -> Option<&Edge> {
        self.borrow().get(&Edge::normalize_edge(v1, v2)).map(|&e| e)
    }

    fn get_weight(&self, v1: u32, v2: u32) -> Option<u32> {
        self.get_edge(v1, v2).and_then(|v| Some(v.get_weight()))
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I added the definition of `Edge` above although it should not matter. Here is the compiler output:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/graph.rs:44:23
   |
44 |         self.borrow().get(&(0,0)).map(|&e| e)
   |                       ^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 41:6...
  --> src/graph.rs:41:6
   |
41 | impl<'a, 'b, B: 'b + Borrow<HashMap<(u32, u32), &'a Edge>>> EdgeFinder for B {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/graph.rs:44:23
   |
44 |         self.borrow().get(&(0,0)).map(|&e| e)
   |                       ^^^
   = note: expected `&HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>`
              found `&HashMap<(u32, u32), &'a Edge>`
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime defined on the method body at 42:17...
  --> src/graph.rs:42:17
   |
42 |     fn get_edge(&self, v1: u32, v2: u32) -> Option<&Edge> {
   |                 ^^^^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/graph.rs:44:9
   |
44 |         self.borrow().get(&(0,0)).map(|&e| e)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Option<&Edge>`
              found `Option<&Edge>`
```

**Edit 2:**
To add a little bit of context, I try to create a wrapper structure around an `EdgeFinder` but I don't want to enforce whether the wrapped `EdgeFinder` is owned or a reference.

```
pub struct EdgeViewer<T: EdgeFinder> {
    inner: T,
}

impl<T: EdgeFinder> EdgeViewer<T> {
  //Obviously works for owned values.
  pub fn new(inner: T) -> Self {
     EdgeViewer { inner }
  }
}
```

However, when using a reference, the following compiler output is shown, which led me to believe that I need to specifically add an implementation for the referenced version.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>: EdgeFinder` is not satisfied
  --> src/construction.rs:74:43
   |
74 |     let mut edge_viewer = EdgeViewer::new(&edges);
   |                                           -^^^^^
   |                                           |
   |                                           the trait `EdgeFinder` is not implemented for `&HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>`
   |                                           help: consider removing the leading `&`-reference
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge> as EdgeFinder>
note: required by `EdgeViewer::<T>::new`
  --> src/graph.rs:58:5
   |
58 |     pub fn new(inner: T) -> Self {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I think that it would be easier to answer if you provide the edge struct and its implementations, and also the exact error message.

Comment: Is this representative of your problem/error message? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7334d7bf4119e6a2efe92f67ae18db0

Comment: I don't understand why you use `Borrow` here. Implementing your trait directly for the `HashMap` works for both owned and referenced `HashMap`s ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16d8840965c6d5784ce32c3d216ee4f5))

Comment: Yeah sorry, I added a little bit more info. @Jmb You are right, however, this does not seem to work when using trait bounds. I added some additional context about my problem which apparently seem to be more relevant than I assumed.

Comment: Does this snippet satisfy your requirements ? [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cdcac2fc6a0ea26aa2ba401a1344b81a)

Comment: @Jerboas86 Yeah, this seems to work, many thanks! But is there really not another way to do this without the duplicated implementation?

Comment: You can avoid the duplicate code with a macro: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d85dfcee1cbe543b82f9dbb56c0327ff)

Comment: There is a way with `Borrow`, but i am not convinced that this is the right way. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3507c19b5fac7aa3f511295ff63ce41b). If it's Ok for you i will make an answer from it ?

Comment: @Jerboas86 Amazing, that works! So just to help me understand, the PhantomData tells the compiler that T might be a reference in which case I would need a lifetime parameter but it could also have an owned value where the lifetime parameter would then remain unused. Is that somewhat correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete solution: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=385b5b84635efa06f8321f2f51135e5a)

```rust
use std::{borrow::Borrow, collections::HashMap, marker::PhantomData, ops::Deref};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Edge {
    between: (u32, u32),
    weight: u32,
}

impl Edge {
    pub fn normalize_edge(v1: u32, v2: u32) -> (u32, u32) {
        (v1.min(v2), v1.max(v2))
    }

    fn get_weight(&self) -> u32 {
        self.weight
    }
}

pub trait EdgeFinder {
    fn get_edge(&self, v1: u32, v2: u32) -> Option<&Edge>;
    fn get_weight(&self, v1: u32, v2: u32) -> Option<u32>;
}

impl EdgeFinder for HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge> {
    fn get_edge(&self, v1: u32, v2: u32) -> Option<&Edge> {
        self.get(&Edge::normalize_edge(v1, v2)).copied()
    }

    fn get_weight(&self, v1: u32, v2: u32) -> Option<u32> {
        self.get_edge(v1, v2).map(|v| v.get_weight())
    }
}

pub struct EdgeViewer<T, U>
where
    T: Borrow<U>,
    U: EdgeFinder,
{
    inner: T,
    __phantom: PhantomData<U>,
}

impl<T, U> EdgeViewer<T, U>
where
    T: Borrow<U>,
    U: EdgeFinder,
{
    pub fn new(inner: T) -> Self {
        EdgeViewer {
            inner,
            __phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<T, U> Deref for EdgeViewer<T, U>
where
    T: Borrow<U>,
    U: EdgeFinder,
{
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.inner
    }
}

fn main() {
    let e1 = Edge {
        between: (0, 1),
        weight: 1,
    };

    let e2 = Edge {
        between: (1, 2),
        weight: 1,
    };

    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert((0, 1), &e1);
    map.insert((1, 2), &e2);

    let viewer: EdgeViewer<_, HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>> = EdgeViewer::new(&map);

    let found_edge = viewer.get_edge(0, 1);

    println!("{:?}", found_edge);
}
```

First, `EdgeFinder` trait is implemented on `HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>`.

Second, the `Borrow<HasMap<K,V>>` trait is implemented on `HasMap<K,V>` and `&HasMap<K,V>`, because `Borrow` trait provides `Borrow<X>` blanket implementations for `X` and `&X` [(docs)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html).

So, `T: Borrow<U>, U: EdgeFinder` trait bound is satisfied by `HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>` and `&HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>` as `T`.

This makes `EdgeViewer::new` accepts `HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>` and `&HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>`, and gives `EdgeViewer` access to `EdgeFinder` trait through its `inner` field.

`Deref` trait is implemented for convenience, but getter to `inner` could also be used.

`PhantomData` is required to remove ambiguity on `U` type. indeed, `Borrow<U>` is a generic trait over U, and so `Borrow` could be implemented on several types. Thanks to `PhantomData`, we can specify that U is `HashMap<(u32, u32), &Edge>`. At least, this is how i understant it.

Note1: `EdgeFinder` implementation on `HashMap<(u32, u32), &'a Edge>` and `&HashMap<(u32, u32), &'a Edge>` is not a valid answer cause it requires several `EdgeFinder` implementations.
[(see playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cdcac2fc6a0ea26aa2ba401a1344b81a)

Note 2: `AsRef` trait can not be used easily here, because it is not implemented on `HasMap<K,V>` and `&HasMap<K,V>`